# why charts appears without plt.show()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

Python 3.6 in Spyder 3.1.4, default preferences, iPython console.

Why do i see the chart with only this line of code, without plt.show() ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [7,8,5,6])
```

Comment: You might be in interactive mode or using an interactive backend?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest details added sorry !

Comment: @DavidG in spyder preferences, for "Graphics Backend", the value is "Inline", do i have to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how to avoid that. In Spyder :
Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Unbox "Activate support"
Reload Spyder.